# How can I use a method inside an activity from external class in java

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

Is it possible to call a method of `Activity` from the regular Java class?

This is the method in the activity:

```
public void showMessage(String mensaje) {
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
          .setCancelable(false)
          .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
              }
          })
          .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
              }
          });
   AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
   alert.show();
```

This is the method of the code in the external (simple java) class:

```
public void write(String importanChange) {
    Context context = //Here I dont know what to do here (It's my question,
                  //but I tried other aproaches but all failed                     
    ((MyActivity)mContext).showMessage(message);
```

The reason is that I have a framework that detects changes on a simulation (Android Aplication) and later this simulation notifies to this framework changes and it decides whether the change is important or not.

So if the change is important the framework must execute the showMessage method in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your method as `public static void write(String importantChange)` instead of `public void write(String importantChange)`

Putting your method 'static' means you don't have to instanciate the class containing your method to use this method.

Edit: I've just seen your "Edit". So, to use a Context in your method, I suggest you pass a context as an argument of your method, like that: `public void write(String importantChange, Context context)`

Comment: 05-21 15:19:21.917: E/AndroidRuntime(406): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Dont matter if I have to pass -Context- to many .class or .java that result in this last method that invokes the corresponding class that execute the write method?

Comment: This exception is typically linked to problems where you try to do stuff to UI-elements on a non-UI-thread.

Comment: Yes, your right..after five days I found the solution...thanks to all of you for your answers (Its help me to find this)...now the corresponding solution was (show last post by me)

Answer (score 0):

As `AlertDialog` doesn't require the `Context` you may choose to create a utility method:

```
public static void showMessage(String message) {
    ...
}

public void write(String importanChange) {
    MyActivity.showMessage(msg);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For eg:

```
Activity Class:


      public class MyActivity extends Activity {

                    onCreate(.....){

               }

         public void go(){

         //Some code

     }



Java External Class in the same package:


public class MyDemo {

     MyActivity ac;
                   public MyDemo(MyActivity ac) {


                           this.ac = ac;
                     }

                 public void foo() {

                          ac.go();    // Access the activity's method
                   }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void showMessage(String importantMensaje){         
        final String mensajeAMostrar = importantMessage;
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() { // This thread runs in the UI
                    public void run() {
                        MyActivity.builder.setMessage(mensajeAMostrar)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Of Course", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              dialog.cancel();
                         }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = MyActivity.builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start(); 
 }
```